# Cron Job in Docker not working - python app

Tags: python, docker, cron, dockerfile, devops

Content within Cron Job seems that's not being executed or there is a problem with saving logs. Let me introduce you to my files:

**crontatab**

```
* * * * * python /bin/wrapper.py > /var/log/somelogfile.txt 2>&1
```

Instead of FROM ubuntu:20.04, I use image with additional layers where python is installed. I can't share this image with you because it's private image.

**wrapper.py**

```
import time
print ("Hello World!")
time.sleep(2)
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y cron busybox

COPY crontab /opt
COPY wrapper.py /bin/wrapper.py
RUN crontab /opt/crontab

CMD busybox syslogd -C; cron -L 2 -f
```

In the running docker I can see that Cron Job is scheduled in each minute (*busybox logread*):
[image]

But logs (so actually "hello world") are not saved into /var/log/somelogfile.txt
I don't know if content is executed within Crontab job or the there is problem with log. I would like to have it saved into log file.

FYI, I can run following command directly from the running docker (-it mode in Docker; /bin/bash):
python /bin/wrapper.py > /var/log/somelogfile.txt 2>&1 and file with 'hello world' is created.

But not by Cron job.

Answer (score 0):

Even you are using an Ubuntu image, python isn't installed by default, so you need to install it. Use this modified dockerfile instead:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y cron busybox
RUN apt-get install -y python3

COPY crontab /opt
COPY wrapper.py /bin/wrapper.py
RUN crontab /opt/crontab

CMD busybox syslogd -C; cron -L 2 -f
```

Additionally modify the crontab command, to user python3 instead of python2:

```
* * * * * python3 /bin/wrapper.py > /var/log/somelogfile.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Instead of FROM ubuntu:20.04, I use image with additional layers where python is installed. I can't share this image with you because it's private image. So this is not the case that python is not installed.

Comment: Then I suggest to log into running container and examine manually.

Comment: I can do ``` sudo docker exec -it name_docker /bin/bash:
python /bin/wrapper.py > /var/log/somelogfile.txt 2>&1 ``` and I get logs saved into txt. But it does not work via Cron Job